# RUN in Dockerfile with systemd as pid 1

Tags: docker, systemd

Is it possible to use `RUN` in a dockerfile while having systemd as pid 1?

I am trying to execute an install script that requires systemd to be present and running on the system, inside a dockerfile. I.e.

```
FROM debian:stable  

RUN apt install -y systemd

RUN someInstallScriptThatRequiresSystemd.sh
```

Comment: Even if you arrange to run `systemd` in a container (which is generally the wrong way to do things), it doesn't really make any sense to interact with it during the `docker build` phase. Each `RUN` command executes a new process, and any processes started by a `RUN` command are shut down before continuing to the next command in the `Dockerfile`. if you can tell us more about your end goal, we might be able to suggest some alternatives.

Comment: I normally wouldn't use an init system in a docker container. I know most of the arguments why it is a bad idea. Unfortunately I have no real say over the matter since the install script relies on the fact that systemd is running in lots of places. I will probably move on to using lxc for now. Just in case anyone cares, I am trying to install multiuser nixpkgs in a docker container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to use RUN in a dockerfile while having systemd as pid 1?

No.  Each `RUN` command generally runs in its own container, and the command itself (or the `sh -c` wrapper Docker provides) will be pid 1.

Also remember that a Docker image doesn't contain running processes, only a filesystem image and metadata that says how to run a container.  You can't persist an image with systemd or other services running, and since the image doesn't container running services, it doesn't make sense to restart a service in a Dockerfile.

Systemd wants to control a *lot* of things, most of which are host-level things that a container shouldn't be thinking about.  You usually shouldn't run it in a container at all; if you must, the better setups remove most of the built-in system-setup tasks.  Better is to use a lighter-weight supervisor like supervisord; better still is to run one process per container, and a minimal init like `tini` if you need it.

If you just need to let this installer run `systemctl`, you can cause that "command" to exist:

```sh
RUN ln -s /bin/true /sbin/systemctl
RUN systemctl restart my-service # does nothing, successfully
```

Comment: The linking systemctl to true trick is neat.